# Liftweb eager_eval and inserting html from db

Tags: lift

I need to execute snippets like:

```
<div class="lift:firstSnippet.content?eager_eval=true">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <div class='lift:secondSnippet.showAddNewForm>'></div>
</div>
```

So in my template I have 
`<div class="lift:firstSnippet.content?eager_eval=true"></div>`

FirstSnippet insert some html from db: 
`def content = "*" #> Unparsed(page.open_!.content.is)` 
That html looks like: 
`<p>Some text</p><div class='lift:secondSnippet.showAddNewForm>'></div>`
 But SecondSnippet doesnt execute. I also tried to use `S.eagerEval(Unparsed(page.open_!.content.is))` 
but result is same. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Sorry, it was typo in class defenition. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you copied your template code over or re-typed it, but there's a syntax error:

```
<div class="lift:firstSnippet.content?eager_eval=true">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <div class='lift:secondSnippet.showAddNewForm>'></div>
</div>
```

Note the `>` at the end of `secondSnippet.showAddNewForm>`

I think it should read:

```
<div class="lift:firstSnippet.content?eager_eval=true">
   <p>Some text</p>
   <div class='lift:secondSnippet.showAddNewForm'></div>
</div>
```

Please try that and see if it makes a difference.